# Django can't convert 'Recipe_instruction' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, django

I am developing an application in django. Here is my models.py and views.py code:

```
#models.py
class Recipe_instruction(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.IntegerField(max_length=500)
    class Meta:
            app_label='recipe_base'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
```

## views.py

```
#create recipes_dict
...
        recipe_instructions = Recipe_instruction.objects.filter(recipe = recipe)
        recipe_instructions_string = ""
        for recipe_instruction in recipe_instructions:
            recipe_instructions_string = recipe_instructions_string + recipe_instruction.content


...
```

My goal is to get all the recipe instructions and pin them together into a single string  `recipe_instructions_string`

But when I run my views.py, it gives me the following error:

```
recipe_instructions_string = recipe_instructions_string + recipe_instruction.content
TypeError: Can't convert 'Recipe_instruction' object to str implicitly
```

Can anyone tell me whats going on?

As recipe_instruction.content is a text field so I shouldn't need to convert it again into a string as its already a string.

**TRACEBACK:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 438, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/worker/worker/views.py", line 500, in Task1
    recipe_instructions_string = recipe_instructions_string + recipe_instruction.content
TypeError: Can't convert 'Recipe_instruction' object to str implicitly
```

Comment: Can you paste the exact stacktrace? doesnt look like the code you are showing is where the error is occuring ?

Comment: TypeError("Can't convert 'Recipe_instruction' object to str implicitly",) is the exception that I get. And yes, I have restarted it after making changes

Comment: Recipe_instruction > RecipeInstruction

Comment: @allcaps can you explain please?

Comment: Its convention to CamelCase your class names. ;)

Comment: But more on topic, you think you are adding strings, but the error says that you are trying to add a RecipeInstruction object to a string. The code you provide seems right. So the problem is somewhere else. The error comes with a full stack trace. Look at the line number as starting point. Than read the code backwards until you find the place where you should supply a string but put in a RecipeInstruction object.

Comment: @Sayse I have included the full traceback

Comment: `/root/worker/worker/tasks.py", line 500` not views.py!

Comment: I modified that part on purpose not to confuse everyone as this is quite a big project and I can't possibly write the entire code in this question

Comment: Do you use Python debugger? `pip install ipdb` and in your code `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()`. Try to load the page. In your console type Python commands. Eg: `isinstance(recipe_instructions_string, basestring)` (False) and `isinstance(recipe_instructions_string, RecipeInstruction)` (True)

Comment: Tip: pdb on /root/worker/worker/views.py:500 would be a good start.

Comment: just for funsies, import your model into a shell `python

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't with the code here.. but whilst we're looking at it, try changing the entire code to

```
instructions = Recipe_instruction.objects.filter(recipe=recipe).values_list('content',
                                                                            flat=True)
recipe_instructions_string  = "".join(instructions)
```

This would stop the error from occuring if it were here, and be more efficient.